# Keyboard shortcut to hide and show Data Output window in pgAdmin 4

Tags: pgadmin-4

Looking for keyboard shortcut key to hide and show Data Output window as shown below in the screenshot.

Using pgAdmin 4 for postgresql 13 version.

I tried the [document](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/development/keyboard_shortcuts.html) but unable to find one.

[image]

Comment: I gave up with pgAdmin long time ago... Can I suggest to take a look to dbeaver?

Comment: There isn't a shortcut key for closing data output windows, but you can hide them by pressing them down.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

There isn't a shortcut key for closing data output windows, but you can hide them by pressing them down **(↕️ - key)**.